# How to redirect to thankyou.html page (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, phpmyadmin

I am trying to redirect to thankyou.html after the mail has been sent but i failed to do.

I have used header option but it was not working with me.
may be i have done something wrong.
when someone submits this query the page should go to thankyou.html, i have already made this page.

this is my php script

```
<?php
include("connect.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $treatment = $_POST['treatment'];
 $gender = $_POST['gender'];
 $date = date('y/m/d');
 $message = $_POST['message'];

 $to = 'enquiry@kbc.com' ;
 $subject = 'Inquiry' ;


 $query = "insert into inquiry 
 (name,email,phone,treatment,gender,date) values       ('$name','$email','$phone','$treatment','$gender','$date')";

if(mysqli_query($db_conx, $query)){

echo "<script>alert('Thank you for submitting your query, our doctors will       call you soon!')</script>";
  }

  mail ( $to,  $subject,  
  "From:"  . $name .  
 ",   Email: " . $email . 
 ",   Number: ". $phone .   
 ",   Gender: " . $gender.
 ",   Treatment: " . $treatment.
 ",   Message: " . $message    );



 }


 ?>
```

Comment: Your code is insecure. It is vulnerable to both [mail header injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_injection)  and [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options here,

1) Either you can use:

```
header('Location: http://domain.com/thank-you.html');
```

2) Use javascript:

```
window.location.href='http://domain.com/thankyou.html';
```

Moreover,
You can post your mail data via Ajax and if data is successfully posted, you can redirect :)

Comment: hi sir can you where i have to write the header option in my code

Comment: You can use after

`echo "<script>alert('Thank you for submitting your query, our doctors will       call you soon!')</script>";`

But since you are already using javascript, javascript is better approach here for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try use `header('Location: http://xxxxxxxx')`
Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
<?php
/* Redirect to a different page in the current directory that was requested */
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'mypage.php';
header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");
exit;
?>
```